# componentDidMount gives 'Request failed with status code 401' when use axios.get

Tags: react-native, mongoose, axios

Hi I am new to react native and node.js I am trying to get user info from database (mongodb). When I use axios.get in render it works fine but it gives a memory error. So I used componentDidMount but it gives 'Request failed with status code 401' error.

```
  async componentDidMount(): void {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('x-auth-token').then(x => this.setState({token: x}));
    setAuthToken(this.state.token);
    await axios.get('http://192.168.1.106:3333/api/auth/')
        .then(r => this.setUserInfo(r)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    await axios.get('http://192.168.1.106:3333/api/profile/me/')
        .then(r => this.setUserProfile(r)).catch(err => console.log(err));

}
```

setAuthToken:

```
const setAuthToken=token=>{
if(token){
    axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token']=token;
}
else{
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'];
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a `await` before `AsyncStorage.getItem` ? It seems to get but haven't return, and  `setAuthToken(this.state.token);` run before `this.setState` ?

Comment: I added await before AsyncStorage.getItem. It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state is not updated immediately. The reason it works in render is because a re-render is being triggered after componentDidMount runs and your state is updated. You should do this

```
async componentDidMount(): void {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('x-auth-token');
  setAuthToken(token);
  await axios.get('http://192.168.1.106:3333/api/auth/')
    .then(r => this.setUserInfo(r)).catch(err => console.log(err));
  await axios.get('http://192.168.1.106:3333/api/profile/me/')
    .then(r => this.setUserProfile(r)).catch(err => console.log(err));
  this.setState({ token });
}
```

If you're only making the call here, then no need to set state.